cifs/SMB automountd not working when moved from 24.04 as on 22.04
I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 24.04.1 on an new SSD.
I would like to take over as much as possible from my old system 22.04, especially the configuration of my automounter, but I can't get it to run on the new system. No matter what I do, I always get log errors. I have managed a manual mount without .credentials file.
What I have done:
I copied the existing .mount and .automount files from the old to the new system. For example:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ben ben 320 Sep 27  2023 mnt-synology-Bilder.mount*

[Unit]
Description=Mount for //192.168.0.10/Bilder
Requires=mnt-synology-Bilder.automount
After=mnt-synology-Bilder.automount
    
[Mount]
What=//192.168.0.10/Bilder
Where=/mnt/synology/Bilder
Options=credentials=/home/ben/.credentials,rw,vers=3.1.1,_netdev,uid=1000,gid=1000
Type=cifs
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

-rwxr-xr-x 1 ben ben 149 Sep 27  2023 mnt-synology-Bilder.automount*

[Unit]
Description=Automount for //192.168.0.10/Bilder
    
[Automount]
Where=/mnt/synology/Bilder
TimeoutIdleSec=1
    
[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target

-r--r----- 1 ben ben 51 Nov 24 23:26 /home/ben/.credentials

username=Ben
password=p!assword!
domain=workgroup

Created a folder to mount:
$ ll /mnt/synology/
insgesamt 0
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30 Nov 24 22:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 88 Nov 24 21:09 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  0 Nov 24 23:46 Bilder/
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  0 Nov 24 22:28 testmount/

Nothing has changed at the NAS (old installation can still do the automount), but when I try to perform the automount on the 24.04 PC, this happens:
    $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    $ sudo systemctl restart mnt-synology-Bilder.automount   
    $ ll /mnt/synology/Bilder/
    ls: cannot access '/mnt/synology/Bilder/': No such device
    $ sudo ls -l /mnt/synology/Bilder/
    ls: cannot access '/mnt/synology/Bilder/': No such device
    $ sudo dmesg
    [  896.726231] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.10/Bilder
    [  896.747517] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
    [  896.747529] CIFS: VFS: \\192.168.0.10 Send error in SessSetup = -13
    [  896.747542] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
    [ 1094.948382] workqueue: delayed_fput hogged CPU for >10000us 8 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
    [ 1143.127709] CIFS: enabling forceuid mount option implicitly because uid= option is specified
    [ 1143.127712] CIFS: enabling forcegid mount option implicitly because gid= option is specified
    [ 1143.127714] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.10/Bilder
    [ 1143.154125] CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

It seems pretty sure it's the cifs-mount itself, not the automountd mechanism. If I change the mounts to NFS, they will work. But then they are no longer secure due to the lack of Kerberos.
I really have no idea what I could be doing wrong, because I didn't really change anything, just copied some files.
I have not created an entry for the mountpoint in /etc/fstab. Why should I?
I've been trying for over 2 hours with ChatGPT (and before that alone for just as long). I tried a thousand things, but nothing worked. The “AI” said it was because of the ! in the password, which was never a problem with 22.04 or before, but the solution approaches. Escaping with \ or with single or double quotation marks did not help and neither did a completely different special character.

Perhaps there has been changes to CIFS between OS. I came across the following link that details this particular error message. https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/1160/unable-mount-cifs-share-error-permission-denied-failed-return-code-13 I thought it might be of some help.

[1] Your credentials file is in your home directory. Is your home directory encrypted? [2] If after a new boot if you run sudo mount -a does it mount successfully?

The error description fits perfectly, as do the comments below it. The only thing is:
@davi The solution suggested there is simply to change the format of the credentials file, and mine already has the format suggested there. :-(

@Morbius

No itś not encript, but if it would be, it should´t make a difference, because the ourtomount is triffered after login.
Sudo mount -a does nothin, because the mount is not listed in fstab. Don´t think it needs to, if i use automountd


And what happens when you either replace _netdev with x-systemd.automount or simply add it as another option.

@Benjamin. Yes but might the format have changed again since link? The follow link doesn't suggest a fix but might suggest a change? Also https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1dec2cq/cifs_unable_to_mount_on_2404lts/

I'd found out that it is definitely not a automount problem, but a cifs problem. Dimply by changing the mount from cifs to NFS - wich works pretty fine.
